# How do I check if a String contains the same letter twice consecutively in php?

Tags: php, html, regex

I don't see why my code doesn't work, any suggestions?

```
$pattern_c_sap='/\.\-/';
$local='.................';
$local_array = explode( '', $local );

for($i=0; $i<=$local_length; $i++){
if(preg_match($pattern_c_sap , $local_array[$i]) && preg_match($pattern_c_sap , $local_array[$i+1])) {
    return false;
}
}
```

I had the following errors: 
The regex should be

```
[/\.\-/]
```

and I should have used str_split instead of explode when splitting for each letter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Warning: explode(): Empty delimiter in this script on line 5

```
$local_array = explode('', $local);
```

Fix would be proper delimiter on explode construct

Comment: While the other solutions are prettier, this is the actual answer to my question on how to fix my code.

Answer (score 18):

You can use a `preg_match` like below:

```
if(preg_match('/(.)\1/', $local, $match){
    echo "contains consecutive characters";
}
```

`(.)` captures a character.

`\1` refers to the captured character.

So, if you have `AA`, the `(.)` captures `A` and `\1` will mean `A`. So the regex will be checking for `AA`.

Comment: Good solution! Additionally you could add an i to make it case insensitive. `'/(.)\1/i'`

Comment: @LarsEbert Indeed. I'm not sure whether or not that's expected, but it's good you mentioned it, in case the OP wants case-insensitivity :)

Comment: This is a great solution, too, I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 5):

```
if (preg_match('/(.)\1/', $str))
    echo "Has 2 same characters consecutively!";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regex quantifiers to match a character a number of consecutive times. like `/\.{2}/`. This will match `.` twice in a row. Or `/g{4}/` will match four consecutive `g`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$pattern = "/(\.|\-)/";
$local='.................';

if (preg_match($pattern, $local, $matches)){
  $num_of_occurences = count($matches)-1 ;
  echo "Number of occurences is {$num_of_occurences}" ;

}
```